# Convergence test for a special type of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence

I have two null sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $a_n \ge 0$ and $b_n \le 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Let $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence with either $c_n=a_n$ or $c_n=b_n$. I do not know which member of $c_n$ is actually $a_n$ and which is $b_n$. I know, that until the n-th member $k(n)$ members of $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are from $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $n-k(n)$ members are from $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

**My Question:** When does the series $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} c_l$ converges? Is there a good convergence test for this problem?

**My Attempt:** The expectational value of $c_n$ should be

$$E(c_n) = \frac{k(n)}{n} a_n + \frac{n-k(n)}{n} b_n$$

So I think, that $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} c_l$ converges iff $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} E(c_l)$ converges. Is this right? Can you point me to a theorem proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ${\bf know}$ which member of $c_n$ is actually $a_n$ and which is $b_n$, if you know all the $k(n)$'s: If $k(n)=k(n-1)$, then $c_n=b_n$, else it is $a_n$. So define $I:=\{n\ :\ k(n)\ne k(n-1) \}$, $$S_N:=\sum_{ {n=1}\atop n\in I}^N a_n\quad \text{and}\quad T_N:=\sum_{ {n=1}\atop n\notin I}^N b_n.$$

So you have that $\sum c_n$ converges if $S_N$ and $T_N$ both converge. You also have that $\sum c_n$ diverges if one of them converges and the other not. If both diverge, then you can say essentially nothing without additional information. The statement: "$\sum c_i$ converges iff $\sum E(c_i)$ converges" is false.

It can happen that $\sum E(c_i)$ diverges and $\sum c_i$ converges: Take $S_N$ and $T_N$ convergent with $I$ and its complement infinite, take $a_i=n/\max(k(n),1)$ for $i\notin I$ and $b_i=0$ for $i\in I$.

It can also happen that $\sum E(c_i)$ converges and $\sum c_i$ diverges:
Take $I=2\Bbb{N}$ and $a_i=1/i$ for $i\in I$ and $ a_i=0$ otherwise, and take $T_N$ convergent and $b_i=0$ for $i\in I$. Then $\sum c_i$ is divergent but $\sum E(c_i)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general test for this kind of problem. Without knowing a and b (and maybe k) it is impossible to say whether the series converges or not. Even if you know all three things, it might be impossible.